# Plot Contour with Gaps in GNUPlot C++? (C++ 14, VS 22)

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I'm attempting to plot a contour plot in the `GNUPlot` C++ library, however I want to be able to plot with holes in the data (without interpolation where there's no data).
I'm using C++ 14, with Visual Studio 2022.

I have the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<float>> data = {};

    for (float x = -5; x <= 5; x += 0.1)
    {
        for (float y = -5; y <= 5; y += 0.1)
        {
            float dist = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
            float z = 1 / dist;

            if ((dist > 0.1) && (z < 0.45))
                data.push_back(vector<float>{x, y, z});
        }
    }

    Gnuplot gp;

    gp << "set title 'test'\n";

    gp << "set dgrid3d 100,100\n";

    gp << "splot" << gp.file1d(data) << "with pm3d title 'test'" << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following contour plot:

[image]

However, in the plot above, the middle "crater" doesn't actually have any data in it:

[image]

The function automatically interpolates any areas without data to create the contour plot.

Is it possible in any way to stop that from happening with the contour functions? So the `GNUPlot` contour functions leave any areas without data empty, instead of interpolating?

Currently I'm using the `dgrid3d` function to create my contour grid, however it does not appear to be possible to achieve my goal with that. Is there a different graphing function that would be better suited to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a comment that "contour plot" means something else entirely to gnuplot.  There are no contours in this plot.

The issue here is that by setting `dgrid3d` you reconstruct the full grid with no hole in it.  Don't do that.  You are generating the data as a grid anyhow, it's just that some of the grid points have a special status.  Here are two ways to do it in gnuplot directly. Note that `dgrid3d` is not used for either method.  I don't know anything about iostream so I leave that layer of coding to you.

**Method 1 -**
Write NaN ("not-a-number") for the points to be omitted.

```
set samples 101,101
set isosamples 101,101
set urange [-5:5]
set vrange [-5:5]

dist(x,y) = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
z(x,y) = 1/dist(x,y)

splot '++' using (dist($1,$2)>0.1 && z($1,$2)<0.45 ? $1 : NaN):2:(z($1,$2)) with pm3d
```

[image]

**Method 2 -**
Write the z value for all points but tell gnuplot to clip at z=0.45

```
set samples 101,101
set isosamples 101,101
set urange [-5:5]
set vrange [-5:5]

dist(x,y) = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
z(x,y) = 1/dist(x,y)

set zrange [*:0.45]
splot '++' using 1:2:(z($1,$2)) with pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply;
Just to clarify, Method 2 worked for me, where I set a higher limit for the Z-axis. The first method appears to not work for me, as inserting NaNs into any place still causes the function to interpolate, as if they were not there.